# Other ways to fill text field, not send_keys

Tags: python, selenium

So I've gone to a few forums online but nothing seems to work. I am trying to fill a credit card field on a website, but when I use:

```
send_keys()
```

It scrambles the numbers. Is there any way to fill the text box similar to the way autocomplete does? Just send the entire string at once:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='__privateStripeFrame4']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
credit_card_text.click()
credit_card_text.send_keys(credit_card)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Update the question with the error you are seeing

Comment: what is the XPath of `credit_card_text`

Comment: @BebanjanB I am not seeing any errors, it is entering into the textbox but it scrambled the numbers.

Comment: @MosheSlavin The xpath is

    ' //*[@id="root"]/form/span[2]/label/input'

Comment: @SebTota see the edit to my answer...

Comment: @MosheSlavin the xpath to credit_card_text is 


'//[@id="root"]/form/span[2]/label/input'

Comment: @SebTota this is not a valid xpath...

Comment: What does "scrambles the numbers" mean? Edit your question and show the before and after strings of numbers. It's hard to tell what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://example.com")
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='__privateStripeFrame4']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
credit_card = 12345678754325
credit_card_text = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/form/span[2]/label/input')))
credit_card_text.click()
credit_card_text.send_keys(credit_card)
```

If it doesn't work you can try using `execute_script`:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@name='__privateStripeFrame4']")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
credit_card = 12345678754325
credit_card_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(' //*[@id="root"]/form/span[2]/label/input')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + credit_card+"')", credit_card_text)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. There were no errors, it just did not fill anything.